# Is this version of the Gaussian distribution function correct?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I am currently doing an exercise in which the following is said:

> Let $f(x, t)$ be the Gaussian distribution function with variance $t$:
> $$
>           f(x, t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi t}} e^{-x^2/2t} $$

But when I look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution the function seems to be different :/ For example, $t$(the variance) is not in the square root with $2 \pi$ in the Wiki link :/

Comment: You wrote it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You are implicitly assuming that:

$$t = \sigma^2.$$

Therefore:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi t}} e^{-x^2/2t} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}~~ \sigma} e^{-x^2/2\sigma^2}.$$

Comment: Oh, thanks sir :)

Comment: But it is not in general true that $\sqrt{a} \cdot \sqrt{b} = \sqrt{a \cdot b}$, right? So why can you do that?

Comment: If $a > 0$ and $b>0$, then $\sqrt{a} \cdot \sqrt{b} = \sqrt{a \cdot b}$ is true. In your case, $a = 2\pi$ and $b = t = \sigma^2.$

Comment: Notice also that for a random variable, $\sigma \geq 0$ by definition.

Comment: Yes, thanks. Appreciate it. Cannot accept answers yet :))

Comment: @ThatGuy ok, but you can upvote it if you like using the triangle pointing up!

Answer (score 0):

Write your $t$ as $t=\sigma ^2$ and you will see that both are equivalent